# Removing the hashtag from AngularJS when working with SailsJS

Tags: angularjs, url, sails.js, angular-ui-router

I'm getting really frustrated with configuring the Routing on our app, which is using sailsJS and angularJS.

The problem is, that the browser doesn't know about angular, so any request like /login returns a 404 Error from sails. I need a solution, to keep the sails routes from the angular ones,

One solution would be to disable html5Mode, but i really don't like the look of URLs with the /#/ which is typical for angular.

I have researched a lot on this and haven't yet found a good answer or maybe a working project for this.

Is what I am trying to do even possible right now?

Comment: just tell sails to return the angular stuffs on every url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using HTML5 mode with Angular, then you need to configure your web server (in this case SailsJS) to respond with your `index.html` file for requests to /login or any arbitrary routes.

If you navigate directly to `http://localhost:3000/login` in your web browser (assuming you're running Sails on localhost:3000), Sails needs to respond with your `index.html` so that your Angular app can bootstrap and then display the appropriate route. Then, subsequent links that the user clicks on in your app will be intercepted directly by the Angular router instead of Sails directly.

Angular has documentation about making HTML5 mode work correctly [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html). Requiring a `<base>` tag is also important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handeled by the application.